# CA1004 and exception/error handling assistance

Tags: c#, generics, exception, code-analysis

[CA1004: Generic methods should provide type parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182150)

```
public static void IfNullAndNullsAreIllegalThenThrow<T>(object value)
{
    if (value == null && !(default(T) == null))
        throw new ArgumentException("Nulls are not allowed for this object.");
}
```

I found this method online, which is quite useful to be honest. But, it violates the CA1004 rule. I'm not sure if there is a better way to design the method and not violate the rules.

---

Sample usage:

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{
    public void SomeMethod(object obj)
    {
        // Ensure the actual object is not null if it shouldn't be.
        ThrowHelper.IfNullAndNullsAreIllegalThenThrow<T>(obj);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a helper method which is only used internally. Make it `internal` instead of `public` and the warning should go away.

Comment: But this is no solution if you want to use these kind of helper methods in one or more assemblies. So you need to duplicate code.

Answer (score 2):

`CA1004` is warning you that the generic type parameter cannot be inferred from the method's signature. Basically, it means you can only call it like this:

```
Something obj = GetSomething();
IfNullAndNullsAreIllegalThenThrow<Something>(obj);
```

On the other hand, if you redefine the method so its argument is of type `T`, then the generic type parameter can be inferred from the object passed:

```
public static void IfNullAndNullsAreIllegalThenThrow<T>(T value)
{
    if (value == null && !(default(T) == null))
        throw new ArgumentException("Nulls are not allowed for this object.");
}
```

So you can simply write:

```
Something obj = GetSomething();
IfNullAndNullsAreIllegalThenThrow(obj);
```

Comment: I think changing the method's signature would make it useless.

Comment: The problem is that I need the parameter to be of type object because that is the type of object that is coming into the other method that does the check.

Comment: @Henrik, can you elaborate on why? I tried to consider all angles and IMHO both `T` and `value` would still be meaningful in the `if` condition...

Comment: The second version can never throw. If `T` is a value type, you cannot pass `null` as a parameter. If `T` is a reference type, `default(T) == null` evaluates to true;

Comment: @Henrik, that's true, but shouldn't that also happen in the first case? If the function is called with a value type, it will be boxed, so `value` won't be `null`. If it's called with a `null` reference type, then `default(T)` will be `null` and the function won't throw. I'm starting to believe it would only work if `T` is not actually the type of `value`.